# Is there any efficient algorithm for determining whether a function is $0$ anywhere in some range?

Tags: roots, piecewise-continuity

Here is my problem in a nutshell. I wanted to detect collisions between lots of different 2D and 3D shapes in a computer program. A lot of them are pretty simple shapes but I was hoping to maybe improve it a little. It occurred to me that I could use indicator functions to improve the collisions.

Suppose there are two objects f and g with indicator functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, where $x$ is a point. Basically the functions return 1 if is in the shape and $0$ if not.

I know that $1 - f(x)g(x)$ is the indicators function for the regions where there's isn't a collision. I wish rob find I find it $0$ anywhere. Seems like an iterative product might work but that's wouldn't work for a computer.

I'm looking for mathematics stance on this. Efficiency is only a concern in the sense that I need it to be performance.

**Edit: In hindsight I cannot think of any situation in which the individual functions won't be piecewise continuous**

Comment: It depends a lot on the properties of the functions you want to investigate. In general for functions that could behave in just about any way there is no better way than to check all points.

Answer (score 2):

You mean, is there any better strategy than checking every point $x \in G$ and see if the indicator function vanishes, e.g. $\chi(x) = 0$?

[image]

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#/media/File:Indicator_function_illustration.png))

This would mean that you have extra information that would allow you to skip certain parts of $G$ from inspection.

There are techniques like bounding volumes and putting them into a spatial hierarchical order, that allow such short cuts.

Comment: Yes. But how do these algorithms manage to avoid checking every point in the domain of the function? Newton-Raphson root finding works by using the property that a function has a derivative. Bisection uses the property that a function is continuous. Your indicator function (in general) does not have these properties. Information from one point $x_1$ will not help you to decide what value it has at a different point $x_2$. You can not avoid checking the value at $x_2$ if you know only the value at $x_1$. So you need extra information.

Answer (score 1):

If the function $$f(z) = f(x+iy) = f_r(x+iy) + i\cdot f_i(x+iy)$$ is differentiable and complex **analytic** with real part $f_r(z)$ and imaginary part $f_i(z)$, all partial derivatives below must be continous and also:

$$\text{Cauchy-Riemann equations for analyticity: }\left\{\begin{align}\frac{\partial f_r}{\partial x} = &\phantom{-.}\frac{\partial f_i }{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial f_r}{\partial y} = &-\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x}\end{align}\right\}$$

or mereomorphic (have a finite countable number of poles, but no essential singularity). Then you could do **Cauchy argument variation** to count the number of zeros inside a contour. That would be a well defined calculation to do as long as you can exclude any non-real roots and poles.

This could be achieved by for example making sure that $C$ includes an infinitesimally thin rectangular slice along the real line: $$\text{Integral line segments } : C=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \cases{1) [a,b] - i\epsilon\\ 2)[b-i\epsilon,b+i\epsilon]\\3)[b,a]+i\epsilon\\4)[a+i\epsilon,a-i\epsilon]}$$

And then calculate this integral and solve for $N$:

$$\oint_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = 2\pi i(N-P)$$

That no poles will occur is ensured by $P=0$ which comes from continuity.